# How to get content from gowalla url?

Tags: php, javascript

How to get content from gowalla url in php or javascript?
Like this:
http://api.gowalla.com/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50

Comment: JS won't be able to do it, due to same-origin security policies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these functions:

1. **Using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)**

   function get_data($url)
   {
     $ch = curl_init();
     $timeout = 5;
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $data;
   }

   $returned_content = get_data('http://api.gowalla.com/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50');
2. **Using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**

   $url = "http://api.gowalla.com/spots?lat=30.2697&lng=-97.7494&radius=50";
   $str = file_get_contents($url);

You can also help with this URL: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl